# How can I encrypt Deja-Dup backups with a GPG public key?

Tags: backup, encryption, deja-dup

Deja Dup, the default backup tool in Ubuntu, allows encryption of backups by means of a password. How can I encrypt my backups using my GPG public key?

[This Debian bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=663951) requests this functionality for an old version of Deja Dup; has the feature been implemented since then?

Answer (score 2):

That feature isn't supported by Deja Dup.

It IS supported by the underlying duplicity command line tool though. See duplicity's man page for help using it.